# SwiftUI List update take high CPU usage

Tags: ios, list, performance, swiftui

I'm developing an app, which have a small view to show download/upload items progress.  I use a SwiftUI list to show them, and the transfering Row will update progress every 300ms.

The issue I meet is that when the list is growing up to **10000** line,  every I change a bit on one line of the list,   the CPU will run at high usage.

My Xcode version is 13.3.1 (13E500a),   Simulator  15.4 iOS.

I've checked this link's solution

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui

This solution is not for my case,  what I meet is that refreshing the List (with 20k lines)  **take high CPU usage**. (exceed 100% on simulator)

Here is the test code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = viewModel()
    @State var items = Array(1...20000)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(){
                Text(vm.itemUpdate)
                ForEach(items, id: \.self ) {
                    Text("Item \($0)")
                }
            }
//            .id(UUID())
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class viewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var itemUpdate: String = ""
    init() {
        activeRefresh(interval: refreshInterval)
    }
    
    //Simulator data update every 200ms
    private var refreshTimer: Timer?
    private let refreshInterval:Double =  0.2
    private func activeRefresh(interval :Double) {
        refreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: refreshInterval, repeats: true) {_ in
            self.itemUpdate = "Dynamic Item \(Int.random(in: 20000..<20100) )"
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode running high CPU 100%:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not Xcode - your timer

Comment: 20000 timers that is to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

Using a view model object and using `id:\.self` are usually big mistakes.

Try moving the timer to an `@State` in the View struct and move the string formatting code into a `Text` in `body`. Then you can remove the object.

Also you have to fix the `ForEach`, the correct syntax for static array of ints is `ForEach(0..<1000)`.